# What is the impact of building Postgres with --disable-thread-safety option?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am a newbie in the database field. Recently I have been trying to install Postgres 9.3.4 on AIX 6.1. When I was building the code with the configure command, I ran into this error:

*checking thread safety of required library functions... no

configure: error: thread test program failed

This platform is not thread-safe.  Check the file 'config.log' or compile

and run src/test/thread/thread_test for the exact reason.

Use --disable-thread-safety to disable thread safety.*

I am only able to compile successfully after using the -disable-thread-safety option. As such, I would like to know what is the impact of using this option towards the database reliability. What does 'client libraries' mean in terms of using the database with this option?

I would also like to know how to compile the thread_test.c and run it manually. The manual says:
        - run "configure" 
        - compile the main source tree
        - compile and run this program

But I haven't been successful in compiling it.

*Edit:
Here are the steps that I took to compile thread_test.c:
1. I first ran configure with the --disable-thread-safety option to get the source tree. 
2. Then from the build directory, I ran "gmake" to compile main source tree.
3. When's that's done, I moved into the src/test/thread folder and tried to run "gmake".
I got this error:

```
`gmake: *** No rule to make target `thread_test.o', needed by `thread_test'.  Stop.
```

If I run "make", I get many errors like this:

```
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 45: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 48: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 52: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 72: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 84: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 85: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 87: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 88: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
"../../../src/Makefile.global", line 91: make: Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.<br>
make: Equal sign not found in macro substitution.<br>
```

I might be doing something wrong here...Can someone be kind enough to point out my mistakes in compiling the src/test/thread/thread_test.c file?

Thanks for all your patience with me. :)

Comment: Show the *exact* error message(s) from compiling `thread_test`

Comment: Hi Craig, I have edited the post to show the problems that I faced when trying to compile thread_test.c. Thanks.

Comment: You must use GNU make. `gmake`.

Comment: I did use `gmake`, and I was in the directory of `src/test/thread` when using the command. This directory already had a Makefile available. I ran into the error described in my post though:
`gmake: *** No rule to make targetthread_test.o', needed by thread_test'.  Stop.`

Comment: Ah, I missed it because of the formatting. Weird issue.

Comment: It builds fine here - gmake 3.82, x86_64 Fedora 20. But you don't really need that test program anyway, unless you plan on fixing the platform code.

Comment: Hm. It's not possible for me to fix the platform code, but I thought it would be a good idea to know why the test is failing/what is wrong with using AIX platform. :) But just to establish - does this also mean that the platform itself affects how libpq is being used?

Comment: Yes, of course the platform affects libpq. `libpq` uses the platform `libc`. If the platform supports pthreads, it uses the platform's threading support. It uses TCP/IP support in the OS... and so on.

Comment: I have figured out why I was unable to compile the thread_test.c - it was because I had a separate build directory from the source tree. It compiled nicely when I had everything in one directory. :) Although now I'm caught in a Catch-22 situation because running the thread_test.exe give me `This PostgreSQL build does not support threads.
Perhaps rerun 'configure' using '--enable-thread-safety'.` But yet I cannot compile using --enable-thread-safety... But I guess this is a different issue now. Thanks Craig, for sharing insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling thread safety will mean that `libpq` can't be safely used with multi-threaded applications unless the app is very careful to only interact with it using a single thread.

This isn't a concern for the great majority of apps.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the reply. Is it accurate to say that I will have to check on how Postgres is being accessed and queried by my program in order to determine if using --disable-thread-safety poses harm or not?

Comment: @evkwan Correct. You need to determine if your client app (a) uses threading and (b) might access libpq from more than one thread at once.